# How to compare two scrolling field

Tags: livecode

How to compare two scrolling field(I have two fields one containing some text and another containing search string & Replace string these are separated by colon. I want to search each word in the first Scrolling field with search string in second scrolling field, If search strings is found in first scrolling field then return the particular words and count of search string in first scrolling field)

```
on mouseUp

   put  the fld  "MytextField" into myHtmll
   put the field SRText into myArrayT
   split myArrayT by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayT) into myArrayl
   repeat with j=1 to myArrayl
      put  myArrayT[j] into k 
      split k by colon
      put k[1] into searchStr1
      put k[2] into replaceStr1
   end repeat

   repeat for each word  dd in field "MytextField"
      if dd contains searchStr1 then
         --put Wordss after mm
         --answer searchStr1
         answer ok
      end if
      answer searchStr
   end repeat

end mouseU
```

Here "MytextField" is the first scrolling field
Here "SRText" is the second scrolling field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   on mouseUp
   set the caseSensitive to true
   put the field SRText into myArrayT
   split myArrayT by CR
   put the number of lines of (the keys of myArrayT) into myArrayl
       put 0 into tmp
    repeat for each key j in myArrayT
      put  myArrayT[j] into k 
      split k by colon


      put k[1] into searchStr1
      put the field "MytextField" into sss
      repeat for each word ass in sss

         if ass contains  searchStr1 then
            add 1 to tmp
            put ass after sam




         end if
      end repeat

   end repeat
   answer sam
      answer tmp
end mouseUP
```